# Retrieving table values from HTML with the same tag names using Beautiful Soup in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve all the `td text` for the below table using Beautiful Soup, unfortunately the tag names are the same and I am either only able to retrieve the first element or some elements are repeatedly printing. Hence not really sure of how to go about it.

Below is HTML table snippet:

```
<div>Table</div>
<table class="Auto" width="100%">
    <tr>
       <td class="Auto_head">Address</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">Name</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">Type</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">Value IN</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">AUTO Statement</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">Value OUT</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">RESULT</td>
       <td class="Auto_head"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
           <td class="Auto_body">1</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">abc</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">yes</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">abc123</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">jar</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">123abc</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">PASS</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">na</td>
    </tr>
```

What I want is all the text content inside these tags for example the first `auto_head` corresponds to first `auto_body` i.e. `Address = 1` similarly all the values should be retrieved.

I have used find,findall,findNext and next_sibling but no luck. Here is my current code in python:

```
self.table = self.soup_file.findAll(class_="Table")
self.headers = [tab.find(class_="Auto_head").findNext('td',class_="Auto_head").contents[0] for tab in self.table]
self.data = [data.find(class_="Auto_body").findNext('td').contents[0] for data in self.table]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the headers first, then use `zip(...)` to combine

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''\
<table class="Auto" width="100%">
    <tr>
       <td class="Auto_head">Address</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">Name</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">Type</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
           <td class="Auto_body">1</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">abc</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
           <td class="Auto_body">2</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">def</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">no</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
           <td class="Auto_body">3</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">ghi</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">maybe</td>
    </tr>
</table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for table in soup.select('table.Auto'):
    # get rows
    rows = table.select('tr')
    # get headers
    headers = [td.text for td in rows[0].select('td.Auto_head')]
    # get details
    for row in rows[1:]:
        values = [td.text for td in row.select('td.Auto_body')]
        print(dict(zip(headers, values)))
```

My output:

```
{'Address': '1', 'Name': 'abc', 'Type': 'yes'}
{'Address': '2', 'Name': 'def', 'Type': 'no'}
{'Address': '3', 'Name': 'ghi', 'Type': 'maybe'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get each *category* first then iterate using `zip`

```
s = '''<div>Table</div>
<table class="Auto" width="100%">
    <tr>
       <td class="Auto_head">Address</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">Name</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">Type</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">Value IN</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">AUTO Statement</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">Value OUT</td>
       <td class="Auto_head">RESULT</td>
       <td class="Auto_head"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
           <td class="Auto_body">1</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">abc</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">yes</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">abc123</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">jar</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">123abc</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">PASS</td>
           <td class="Auto_body">na</td>
    </tr></table>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s,features='html')
head = soup.find_all(name='td',class_='Auto_head')
body = soup.find_all(name='td',class_='Auto_body')
for one,two in zip(head,body):
    print(f'{one.text}={two.text}')
```

---

```
Address=1
Name=abc
Type=yes
Value IN=abc123
AUTO Statement=jar
Value OUT=123abc
RESULT=PASS
=na
```

---

[Searching by CSS class](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attrs)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to add the find_all method at the end of the find
so your code will be

```
source = requests.get('YOUR URL')
soup=BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')

data = soup.find('tr').find_all('td')[0]
data = soup.find('tr').find_all('td')[1]
```

and so on just change the last list number 0,1,2... or else use for loop for the same